# Date function to display the date as mm/dd/yy

Tags: date, vbscript

I'm trying to get the date in mm/dd/yy format using VB Script.

But I couldn't find any function to do the requirement , can some help me here please?

Answer (score 5):

I like to use the .NET stringbuilder, because I can switch formats on the fly by just adapting the format specifier instead of using string manipulation:

```
wscript.echo CreateObject("system.text.stringbuilder").AppendFormat("{0:MM}/{0:dd}/{0:yy}", now).ToString()
```

Comment: so far, this is the *only* correct answer: FormatDateTime puts you at the mercy of the current reginoal settings; 'rolling your own format function' risks not meeting the specs (mmddyyy may be 'better' than mm/dd/yy, but it's not what the OT ordered).

Answer (score 2):

A one-line alternative that doesn't require .NET:

```
d = Right("0" & Month(Date), 2) & "/" & Right("0" & Day(Date), 2) & "/" & Right(Year(Date), 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

FormatDateTime function formats and returns a valid date:

```
FormatDateTime(date,2)
```

Comment: This does not comply with the specified formatting `mm/dd/yy` in my locale (I get 24/2/2014).

Answer (score 0):

For locale independent formatting:

```
function mmddyyyy(input)
    dim m: m = month(input)
    dim d: d = day(input)
    if (m < 10) then m = "0" & m
    if (d < 10) then d = "0" & d

    mmddyyyy = m & "/" & d & "/" & right(year(input), 2)
end function
```