# How can I rename a file in vbscript so as to contain timestamp?

Tags: vbscript, timestamp

Problem: Rename the file to “Result_[timestamp].csv”, where timestamp has format yyyymmddhhmmss

The file is on D:/path/mytest.csv

Thanks!

Comment: what is your problem ? what is your need ?

Comment: Post what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `MoveFile` method of the FileSystemObject or the Name property of the File object. For example:

```
CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").MoveFile strOldFileName, strNewFileName
```

Or:

```
CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFile(strOldFileName).Name = strNewFileName
```

As for formatting the date, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985545/date-function-to-display-the-date-as-mm-dd-yy) post from earlier today.

Good luck.