# VBA script to Rename file with time stamp appended

Tags: vbscript

I have a zip file saved in D:VB/practice/snapshot.zip Can some one help me with VB code to rename the file with appending current time stamp at the end of the file name?

i am completely new to VB scripting, can some one please quickly help.

i have written below code which is  giving out me error Error: Object required : 12/10/20186:21:18 PM

```
DIM FSO 
SET FSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
DIM date1 
date1 = Now() 
FSO.MoveFolder "D:\VB practice\Folder2.gz.zip","D:\VB practice\Folder2" & 
date1.gz.zip 

Set FSO = Nothing
```

can some one  please find out for me where is the error

Thanks,
Sonu

Comment: VB, VBA and VB script are three different things. VBA only runs inside office. VBScript doesn't. If you google for it you'll find it very quickly. Lets race

Comment: Oh look heres one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22000233/how-can-i-rename-a-file-in-vbscript-so-as-to-contain-timestamp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I rename a file in vbscript so as to contain timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22000233/how-can-i-rename-a-file-in-vbscript-so-as-to-contain-timestamp)

Comment: This one actually has fully working code. https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1364176

Comment: Thank you so Much For Quick response.

Comment: Actually it is an VBS, i have written below code giving out me error

Error: Object required : 12/10/20186:21:18 PM

DIM FSO
SET FSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
DIM date1 
date1 = Now()
FSO.MoveFolder "D:\VB practice\Folder2.gz.zip","D:VB practice\Folder2" & date1.gz.zip

Set FSO = Nothing

can you please find out for me where is the error

Comment: You didn’t submit the code you wrote “below”. Please edit it into your question instead

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there. In future, post the code in the first place!

Comment: Here we go added code in question can some one help me to rectify the error

Answer (score 0):

It's going to error when you try and move the file:

```
FSO.MoveFolder "D:\VB practice\Folder2.gz.zip","D:VB practice\Folder2" &
```

You are missing the `\` after `D:` in the second instance.

Edit: here is a fixed script for you @Vaseem Syed

```
DIM FSO 
SET FSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
DIM date1 
date1 = Now() 
FSO.MoveFolder "D:\VB practice\Folder2.gz.zip","D:\VB practice\Folder2" & date1 & ".gz.zip"
Set FSO = Nothing
```

Comment: sorry  while editing to post here i missed the \ , can you please try to answer here?

Comment: Also this: `date1.gz.zip` needs to be `date1 & ".gz.zip"`

Comment: Put this in there and you will see the problem: `msgbox date1`. You can't use a `:` in a filename. Use the replace function to replace it with either a `-` or an underscore or split it up and take only the date.